# What is the exact form of the interaction Hamiltonian mentioned in Schwartz's book?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, electromagnetic-radiation, hamiltonian, fermis-golden-rule

In the book "Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model" by Schwartz, in eq. (1.24) of chapter 1, he mentions that the interaction Hamiltonian for a particle going from state $i$ to $f$ is of the form:

[image: eqn]

My question is how can the interaction Hamiltonian have the creation and annihilation operators in it?

The Hamiltonian in the general sense as per my understanding, doesn't necessarily have these kind of terms. At least that much I had studied till now in quantum mechanics. But here, when the Hamiltonian is written like that and I am confused. If any one could clarify on this, that will be great.

Comment: "...how can the interaction Hamiltonian have the creation and annihilation operators in it?" How can it not?

Comment: @hft because here we are assuming by default that the Hamiltonian already has the creation and annihilation operators which is responsible for adding new particles to the state or removing them. But my question is what would have happened if the Hamiltonian did not have this kind of structure or had some other terms like that of an SHO?

Comment: "If the Hamiltonian did **not** have this structure..." (Emphasis added.) I don't understand. You posted a question about a Hamiltonian with a given structure and you seem to be asking about that Hamiltonian... But now you are saying you want to consider some *other* Hamiltonian? In that cause, you need to specify what other Hamiltonian you are interested in. You could be asking about *anything*... How can we answer such a poorly defined question?

Comment: My argument is that why that hamiltonian contains the creation and annihilation operators. Now, instead of answering that question, you are asking me a question that how can it not have? If I had understood that, I wouldn't have posted the question in the first place.

Comment: I'm just asking you to clarify your question. It might be clear to you, but it is not clear to me. I would like to answer if I can, but I currently don't understand the question well enough to answer.

Comment: See, my question is, while describing the interaction Hamiltonian in the case for which some excitation puts some particles from a state $i$ to another state $f$, the author tells that the interaction Hamiltonian in this case will have that structure. I don't understand why does it has creation and annihilation operators or more of their order?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to have the form: $H_I^\dagger a^\dagger + H_I a$, but that form is common. For example, if you write out a quantum mechanical dipole interaction like $\sim \omega q\vec r \cdot \vec A$ you get your field contributing terms that are a linear combo of the creation and annihilations operators $\hat a_{\vec k}$. (This is because the field $\vec A(\vec r)$ looks like $\vec A \sim \sum_k (\vec \epsilon a_k e^{ikx} + \vec \epsilon^* a_k^\dagger e^{-ikx})$.

Comment: Okay so is it like some kind of mode expansion of the Hamiltonian?

Comment: Yeah it could be. For example, if there was only one mode in the electric field, the dipole interaction term I wrote above would look like: $H_I^\dagger a^\dagger + H_I a$, where $H_I = \omega q \vec r \cdot \vec \epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

It's clearer looking at equations 1.25, 1.26 where the state of system is a composition (external product) of the state of the atom and of the field. You must have scale operators of the field if you want to consider (with non-null probability density) all the transitions between initial and final states with different number of photons e.g. absorption processes, that otherwise are not included in your theory

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you are saying that, because we need to add or remove particles from the state or we need the particles to transit from one state to another, the creation and annihilation operators can do that for us and that is why they are included. Am I correct?

Comment: Basically yes: you want a non null non-diagonal elements of the hamiltonian operator, meaning that you want expectation values of $\hat{H}$ between different states of the system to be non null. Only this way you are able to describe interaction processes.